# Swift: Cast tableCell as variable class

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to refine some **working** but **ugly** code.

My app has five TableViews, each one displaying a different type of data (with different cell layouts). Because the datatypes are similar-ish and require many similar methods (for downloading, encoding, etc), I have set up a TableViewController:UITableViewController class to serve as a superclass for the five TableViewController subclasses. Within this superclass, I have the standard "cellForRowAt" method, but it's bloated and repetitive. I want to simplify it.

My problem (I think) is the multiple "let cell = " statements, which all cast as a different type of TableViewCell depending on the datatypes. For example, my DataType.SCHEDULES datatype needs to get a SchedulesTableViewCell with reuseID of "SchedulesCell". I can't make them all the same TableViewCell class, because they each have their own IBOutlet views.

Making things uglier, each tableView has two cell prototypes, and I need to be able to generate an ARTICLE cell and a DETAIL cell for each datatype.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // get the article and row type
    let article = getArticleFor(indexPath: indexPath)
    let cellType = getCellTypeFor(indexPath: indexPath)

    // create either an ARTICLE row or a DETAIL row.
    // (simplified for SO posting. Each "case" is actually 
    // 5-6 lines of nearly identical code)
    switch cellType {

    // for the ARTICLE cell prototype
    case CellType.ARTICLE:

        // get the right table cell matching the datatype
        switch self.datatype {

        case DataType.SCHEDULES:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SchedulesCell") as! SchedulesTableViewCell
            cell.fillCellWith(article: article)
            cell.otherMethod2()
            cell.otherMethod3()
            return cell

        case DataType.LUNCH:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LunchCell") as! LunchTableViewCell
            cell.fillCellWith(article: article)
            cell.otherMethod2()
            cell.otherMethod3()
            return cell

        case DataType.EVENTS:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "EventsCell") as! EventsTableViewCell
            cell.fillCellWith(article: article)
            cell.otherMethod2()
            cell.otherMethod3()
            return cell

        case DataType.DAILY_ANN:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DailyannCell") as! DailyannTableViewCell
            cell.fillCellWith(article: article)
            cell.otherMethod2()
            cell.otherMethod3()
            return cell

        case DataType.NEWS:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NewsCell") as! NewsTableViewCell
            cell.fillCellWith(article: article)
            cell.otherMethod2()
            cell.otherMethod3()
            return cell

        }
    // or for the DETAIL cell prototype
    case CellType.DETAIL:

        // get the right table cell matching the datatype
        switch self.datatype {

        case DataType.SCHEDULES:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SchedulesDetailsCell") as! ScheduleDetailTableViewCell
            cell.fillCellWith(article: article)
            cell.otherMethod2()
            cell.otherMethod3()
            return cell

        case DataType.LUNCH:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LunchDetailsCell") as! LunchDetailsTableViewCell
            cell.fillCellWith(article: article)
            cell.otherMethod2()
            cell.otherMethod3()
            return cell

        case DataType.EVENTS:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "EventsDetailsCell") as! EventsDetailTableViewCell
            cell.fillCellWith(article: article)
            cell.otherMethod2()
            cell.otherMethod3()
            return cell

        case DataType.DAILY_ANN:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DailyannDetailCell") as! DailyannDetailsTableViewCell
            cell.fillCellWith(article: article)
            cell.otherMethod2()
            cell.otherMethod3()
            return cell

        case DataType.NEWS:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NewsDetailCell") as! NewsDetailTableViewCell
            cell.fillCellWith(article: article)
            cell.otherMethod2()
            cell.otherMethod3()
            return cell
        }
    } 
}
```

I originally had each "let cell =" case within the subclasses' own "cellForRowAt" methods, but I was repeating very similar code in every subclass, which seemed silly. On the other hand, the code above moved the repetition into a single class, but didn't remove the repetition, so it's still silly, but in a different place.

I feel like if I could make a dictionary of classes, something like this...

```
let tableCellClasses = [DataType.SCHEDULES : ScheduleTableViewCell,
                    DataType.LUNCH : LunchTableViewCell
                    etc.
```

...then I could make my "let cell = " statements more generic, like...

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier[dataType]) as! tableCellClasses[dataType]
```

but can't seem to find a way to make it work.

As I said, it works but it's ugly. I work in a high school, so I'd like for students viewing the repo to see clean, well-structured code -- so I'm shooting for better than just "it works."

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Swift's meta types and what not, but looking at your code, all your cell subclasses share the same methods:

```
cell.fillCellWith(article: article)
cell.otherMethod2()
cell.otherMethod3()
```

Why not:

- Have a base class from which all custom cell classes inherit, that implements the above interface (the three methods you use after dequeuing a cell, with the possibility of them being overriden on each concrete subclass), so dequeue once and force-cast into the base type (I believe the right implementation of the methods will be executed, for each subclass. The cast is only to make the compiler happy: `UITableViewCell` does not have those methods).
- Have a switch clause on the data type that gives you the specific **cell identifier**
- Have each prototype cell set to the specific class on the storyobard, and assign the specific identifier too.

Does it make sense?

Now, form looking at your code, it doesn't look like you really need different *subclasses*. It's perfectly okay to have several different protoypes of the **same** `UITableViewCell` subclass, each with a different subview layout and a different reuse identifier, as long as they all can work with the same number and type of subviews and other custom properties/methods.

Comment: If I make a TableViewCell base class, then the it won't have access to my IBOutlet views in the subclasses. So when I call my "let cell =" statements, if those are cast as the base class, then base class methods can't populate the subclasses cell views.

Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: I think that if you set the appropriate subclass for each prototype cell in the identifiy inpsector, the storyboard instantiates it as requested. Casting to the base class does not "convert it" to an instance of the base class (which it, in a sense, already is)., but it lets you call `fillCellWith(article:)` without having a compiler error. If the specific subclass overrides the method, the overriden implementation is called. The outlet setup should be performed in the cell subclass source code, so it is an implementation detail isolated from your table view controller.

Comment: And probably use `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:, for:)`

Comment: I tried it and it worked! I still feel funny about it, like it's a trick. I feel like casting as the base class should be giving me trouble. Anyway, it's much better now, thanks!

Comment: Casting just tells the compiler to treat the instances as if they are objects of the base class (which they are, and more). By virtue of being subclasses of the base class, they all **do** have an implmemention of the methods called (although which implementation is actually executed depends on the specific subclass, but that's irrelevant).

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to do what you assume. You have to casting the classes one by one for your need. Or you can use base class which implemented all methods you need and calling them by the datatype.